# How do I convert multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is a research database which has (yes I know poorly designed) a database which includes a questionnaire for participants. This questionnaire is asked to the participant at three times in the study (P1/P2/P3)

The table structure for the questionaire;

Questionaire 1.

```
+--+-------+--------+--+--+--+--+--+---
|PK|Part_ID|Phase_Id|Q1|q2|q3|q4|q5|...
+--+-------+--------+--+--+--+--+--+---
|1 |A010   |P1      |1 |0 |1 |0 |1 |...
+--+-------+--------+--+--+--+--+--+---
|2 |A010   |P2      |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |...
+--+-------+--------+--+--+--+--+--+---
|3 |A010   |P3      |1 |0 |1 |0 |1 |...
+--+-------+--------+--+--+--+--+--+---
```

so forth for each participants.

All participants have a maximmum of 3 Phases, may have less. Due to the table structure column count is always the same.

The researcher wants to get all the data onto a single line for input into an analytical program (SPSS).  So the output structure need to look like this

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Part_ID|P1_Q1|P1_q2|P1_q3|P1_q4|P1_q5|P2_Q1|P2_q2|P2_q3|P2_q4|P2_q5|P3_Q1|P3_q2|P3_q3|P3_q4|P3_q5|
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|A010   |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Using SQL Server 2008 Express.

I had a look at a few pivot and unpivot examples and dont think they are the right way to go (no aggregation required).

So any pointers would be great.

Regards

Roger
(I hope the Demo format comes out ok).

Comment: You mean a single row ***per participant*** right?

Comment: Martin - Yes thanks. 1 row per participant

Comment: How did you format this in table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UPIVOT` your table first and `PIVOT` it again

```
SELECT Part_Id, 
       P1_Q1, P1_Q2, P1_Q3, P1_Q4, P1_Q5,
       P2_Q1, P2_Q2, P2_Q3, P2_Q4, P2_Q5,
       P3_Q1, P3_Q2, P3_Q3, P3_Q4, P3_Q5
  FROM
(
  SELECT Part_ID, Phase_Id + '_' + Question Question, Value
    FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT Part_ID, Phase_Id, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5
      FROM Table1
  ) s
  UNPIVOT
  ( 
    Value FOR Question IN (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5) 
  ) u
) s
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Value) FOR Question IN 
  (
    P1_Q1, P1_Q2, P1_Q3, P1_Q4, P1_Q5,
    P2_Q1, P2_Q2, P2_Q3, P2_Q4, P2_Q5,
    P3_Q1, P3_Q2, P3_Q3, P3_Q4, P3_Q5
  )
) p
```

or by using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Part_Id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P1' THEN Q1 END) P1_Q1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P1' THEN Q2 END) P1_Q2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P1' THEN Q3 END) P1_Q3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P1' THEN Q4 END) P1_Q4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P1' THEN Q5 END) P1_Q5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P2' THEN Q1 END) P2_Q1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P2' THEN Q2 END) P2_Q2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P2' THEN Q3 END) P2_Q3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P2' THEN Q4 END) P2_Q4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P2' THEN Q5 END) P2_Q5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P3' THEN Q1 END) P3_Q1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P3' THEN Q2 END) P3_Q2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P3' THEN Q3 END) P3_Q3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P3' THEN Q4 END) P3_Q4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Phase_id = 'P3' THEN Q5 END) P3_Q5
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Part_Id;
```

Output:

```
| PART_ID | P1_Q1 | P1_Q2 | P1_Q3 | P1_Q4 | P1_Q5 | P2_Q1 | P2_Q2 | P2_Q3 | P2_Q4 | P2_Q5 | P3_Q1 | P3_Q2 | P3_Q3 | P3_Q4 | P3_Q5 |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|    A010 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8daf7/12)** demo

Comment: Much appreciate your comprehensive response and example.  I am in the process to adapt this to our live information and will get back to you.  I do have 1 question, how does `Phase_Id + '_' + Question Question` work.  I don't fully understand 'question question'

Comment: The max aggregation would be interesting on how expensive in processing that would be.  I will see if i can execute the plan.  I love the SQL fiddle scenario.....

Comment: You're very welcome. After unpivot column `question` contains values of `q1, q2, q3 etc.`. Then in the outer select values of `Phase_Id` and `Question` concatenated to form values (like `P1_Q1`) to become column names after pivot.

Comment: Ofcourse... the second question is the column header... I am a bit slow. Its amazing how you can read things in a way and get stuck on it. BTW the SQL fiddle shows that the second example is less expensive on IO than the first, not by much.  Admittedly I was surprised, but the extra cost was in the sort.

Comment: Yes thanks it did, but there is one step further which is out of scope for this question and that is to create the table/out via dynamic sql (as there are several different survey requiring the same attention).  If you have any pointers in this direction..... I havent had the time to go that far with it yet as I am only helping out in my spare time.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of phases is a maximum of 3 then you can use `LEFT JOIN`s, for example something like:

```
SELECT p1.Part_ID, p1.q1, p1.q2, p1.q3, p1.etc,
p2.Part_ID, p2.q1, p2.q2, p2.q3, p2.etc,
p3.Part_ID, p3.q1, p3.q2, p3.q3, p3.etc,
FROM Questionaire p1 
LEFT JOIN Questionaire p2 ON p1.Part_ID = p2.Part_ID AND p1.PhaseId='P1' AND p2.PhaseId='P2'
LEFT JOIN Questionaire p3 ON p2.Part_ID = p3.Part_ID AND p3.PhaseId='P3'
```

I haven't tried this so the syntax might not be quite right (e.g. you may need some brackets).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have currently implemented this style of solution but it is very slow. I was trying to be smart about the coding and have a more efficient in processing.  But appreciate the effort to respond- Roger

Comment: There's no reason that simple joins like this should be slow. Do you have indexes on Questionnaire.Part_ID and Questionnaire.PhaseId?

Comment: Probably no indexes and havent been able to trouble shoot... It is running on a desktop with SQl express so i wasnt surprised that it would take a few minutes to generate.  I will put indexes in place to see if that speeds things up.  Thanks for the extra hint here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Part_ID, SUM(P1_Q1) P1_Q1, SUM(P1_Q2) P1_Q2, SUM(P1_Q3) P1_Q3,
SUM(P1_Q4) P1_Q4, SUM(P1_Q5) P1_Q5, SUM(P2_Q1) P2_Q1, SUM(P2_Q2) P2_Q2,
SUM(P2_Q3) P2_Q3, SUM(P2_Q4) P2_Q4, SUM(P2_Q5) P2_Q5, SUM(P3_Q1) P3_Q1,
SUM(P3_Q2) P3_Q2, SUM(P3_Q3) P3_Q3, SUM(P3_Q4) P3_Q4, SUM(P3_Q5) P3_Q5
FROM 
(  
SELECT Part_ID,P1_Q1,P1_Q2,P1_Q3,P1_Q4,P1_Q5,P2_Q1,P2_Q2,P2_Q3,P2_Q4,P2_Q5,
P3_Q1,P3_Q2,P3_Q3,P3_Q4,P3_Q5,P4_Q1,P4_Q2,P4_Q3,P4_Q4,P4_Q5,P5_Q1,P5_Q2,P5_Q3,
P5_Q4,P5_Q5
FROM 
(SELECT PK, Part_Id, Phase_id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Phase_id +'_Q1' AS LocQ1, 
Phase_id + '_Q2' LocQ2, Phase_id + '_Q3' LocQ3, Phase_id + '_Q4' LocQ4,
Phase_id+'_Q5' LocQ5
FROM #t) AS pvt
PIVOT(SUM(Q1) FOR LocQ1 IN (P1_Q1, P2_Q1, P3_Q1, P4_Q1, P5_Q1)) AS pvt1
PIVOT(SUM(q2) FOR LocQ2 IN (P1_Q2, P2_Q2, P3_Q2, P4_Q2, P5_Q2)) AS pvt2
PIVOT(SUM(q3) FOR LocQ3 IN (P1_Q3, P2_Q3, P3_Q3, P4_Q3, P5_Q3)) AS pvt3
PIVOT(SUM(q4) FOR LocQ4 IN (P1_Q4, P2_Q4, P3_Q4, P4_Q4, P5_Q4)) AS pvt4
PIVOT(SUM(q5) FOR LocQ5 IN (P1_Q5, P2_Q5, P3_Q5, P4_Q5, P5_Q5)) AS pvt5
) x GROUP BY Part_ID
```

Comment: This is similar to Peterm solution, but i would consider the expensiveness on running this query with the quantitiy of aggregation.  Thanks for the effort in responding.